# React JS wait for useeffect to finish all renders

Tags: reactjs

I have the next situation in my react application. I have a state that is set from another component:   `const [test, setTest] = useState();`, when this state is set it create some renders like:

1. first render `test = first value`
2. second render `test = first value`
3. last render `test = the expected value`. 
   What i want to do is to read only the last value of test inside useEffect hook like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // here i need to avoid the previous values of test and to display only the last
  console.log(test);
}, [test]);
```

Question: How inside useEffect to avoid the previous values of `test` and to display only the last?

Comment: Please don't post [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556511/wait-till-the-last-render-and-get-the-last-value-in-reatjs#comment119408044_67556511)

Comment: @Yousaf, i will remove that question

Comment: Probably use debounced function that will be triggered  when no updates are received within time window. This is design problem, as mentioned in comments

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise a counter variable outside the uesEffect, and increment it everytime the useEffect runs. Once you the desired condition is met(eg, if(counter===2)), then run console.log.

so

```
let counter = 0;
useEffect(()=>{
counter++;
if(counter==2){
   console.log(test)
}
},[test])
```

Comment: i don't know how many renders will be, and the expected value is dynamic

Comment: do you know how many renders need to be skipped?

Comment: Then you need to change your design. This is because in your current design, you have a dependency on the future. At any given point, the program has no way of knowing if it is the last render. It can never guarantee that there isn't going to be another render after the current one. What you could do is find out what is causing that render, and then use an if to see if that particular condition is met and console log it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the best solution is to wait for the 3rd call of the useEffect. It already means that the first 2 renders are useless, not too optimized but ok...

On the other hand, why not just test the value where you need it?

`if(!!test && test === expectedValue)`

or in jsx / tsx :

`{!!test && test === expectedValue && <></>}`

Comment: the expected value is dynamic

Comment: So set test to null at the beginning, and test if the state is null or not ?
Operator `!!test` can do this, It tests if the vari exists and if it is not null or undefined